# How to display custom sidebar in specific WooCommerce category?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, product

I have specific question about WooCommerce plugin.

I am using `WooCommerce Product Categories` widget to show category menu on the left sidebar.

On my website I have a category for special offers (which contains some subcategories and products) and I want other categories to be hidden from `Woocommerce Product Categories` widget when user opens this `"Special Offers"` category.

I already tried to create custom sidebar to show only on this category but without luck.

How can I achieve this?

Maybe I can create two seperate widgets - one will display list of category `"Special offers"` subcategories and second widget will display other categories & its subcategories but.. how to show these widgets with that kind of conditional logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**---- Update *(related to your comment)* ----**

You need to use the conditional `is_product_category( 'my_category_slug' )`.

Reference: **[WooCommerce Conditional Tags](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/conditional-tags/#a-product-category-page)**

You should try then this, to include also all subcategories of your 'special_offers' category.

```
if ( is_product_category( 'special_offers' ) || is_product_category( array( 'my_sub_category1', 'my_sub_category2', 'my_sub_category3' ) ) ) {

    // My custom side-bar code for "Special Offers" category

} else {

    // My custom side-bar code for all other products

}
```

Fine tune (adding or removing subcategories) and replace 'my_subcategory1', 'my_subcategory2', 'my_subcategory3' by your subcategories slugs, please.

Comment: I tried but widget doesn't show up when I am opening any subcategory.